# Resize all images in directory

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

```
<?
/*
* Class: SimpleImage, Author: Simon Jarvis, Copyright: 2006 Simon Jarvis, Date: 08/11/06
* Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php
* See the GNU General Public License for more details: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/

class SimpleImage {
   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {
      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {
         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {
      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {
      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {
      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }
}
// End of SimpleImage class

/* Directory Listing
Source : http://www.spoono.com/php/tutorials/tutorial.php?id=10
*/

// Define the path as relative
$path = "/home/content/51/6511651/html/SITE/img2";

// Using the opendir function
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("ERROR: Cannot open  <b>$path</b>");

echo("Directory Listing of $path<br/>");

//running the while loop
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))
{
   if($file != "." && $file != "..")
   {
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load("/img2/new".$file);
    $image->resize(86,86);
    $image->save("img2/new/s".$file);
    echo("&bull; $file <br>");
   }
}

//closing the directory
closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

Why won't this script do anything???? I was trying to get it configured from (http://www.webmastersucks.com/resizing-all-images-in-directory/) and it basically does nothing once i run it.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, after this line:

```
$path = "/home/content/51/6511651/html/SITE/img2";
```

Add this one:

```
if (getcwd() != $path) chdir($path);
```

...to make sure you are working in a directory that allows you to use the relative paths you are trying to.

Then, change the contents of the `while` loop to this:

```
if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
  $image = new SimpleImage();
  $image->load($file);
  $image->resize(86,86);
  $image->save("s".$file);
  echo("&bull; $file <br>");
}
```